# Query Parse.com migrated database pointer relationship with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, mongoose

### Context

So we have migrated from Parse.com to an hosted MongoDB database. Now I have to write a script that queries our database directly (not using Parse).

I'm using nodejs / mongoose and am able to retrieve these documents.

### Problem

[image: Document with relation ship example]

Here is my schema so far:

```
var StorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: String,
  genre: String
});

var ActivitySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: String,
  action: String,
  _p_story: String /* Also tried: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' } and { type: String, ref: 'Story' }*/,
});
```

I would like to write a query that fetches theses documents with the related Story (stored as a pointer).

```
Activity
  .find({
    action: 'read',
  })
  .exec(function(error, activities) {
    activities.forEach(function(activity) {
      // I would like to use activity._p_story or whatever the mean to access the story here
    });
  });
```

### Question

Is there a way to have the fetched activities populated with their story, given that the `_p_story` field contains `Story$` before the object id?

Thanks!

Comment: Just commenting, but you could run your own parse server instead of rewriting all the queries. https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server. The sample applications make it easy, section "Parse Server Sample Application".

Comment: I have been looking to do the same thing to get around some limitations. Were you able to pull this off?

Answer (score 0):

One option I have been looking at is the ability to create a custom data type for each pointer. The unfortunate side is Parse treats these as 'belongsTo' relationships and but does not store the 'hasMany' relationship that Mongoose wants for `populate()`. But once this is in place you can easily do loops to get the relational data. Not ideal but works and is what populate is really doing under the hood anyways.

PointerTypeClass.js -> This would work for populating the opposite direction.

```
var Pointer = function(mongoose) {

    function PointerId(key, options) {
        mongoose.SchemaType.call(this, key, options, 'PointerId');
    }

    PointerId.prototype = Object.create(mongoose.SchemaType.prototype);

    PointerId.prototype.cast = function(val) {
        return 'Pointer$' + val;
    }

    return PointerId;
}


module.exports = Pointer;
```

Also be sure mongoose knows about the new type by doing `mongoose.Schema.Types.PointerId = require('./types/PointerTypeClass')(mongoose);`

Lastly. If you are willing to write some cloudcode you could create the array of ids for your populate to know about the objects. Basically in your Object.beforeSave you would update the array of the id for the relationship. Hope this helps.